# Coldfusion cfldap: List all members of a list of AD OU groups

Tags: coldfusion, active-directory, ldap

We have a list of OU groups that a subset of our users belong to. Some users belong to multiple OU groups.

Is it possible to use cfldap to return all users who belong to one or more of this list of OU groups?  Something like this:

```
<cfldap
    name="user_info"
    action="QUERY"
    server="123.45.6.78" 
    attributes="displayName, givenName, memberOf" 
    start="dc=na,dc=company,dc=lan"
    scope="subtree"
    filter="(|(memberOf CONTAINS ou=OU001)(memberOf CONTAINS ou=OU002)(memberOf CONTAINS ou=OU003))"
    username="#userName#"
    password="#passWord#">
```

Answer (score 2):

you should be able to set your filter like this

```
filter = "(|(memberOf=*ou=OU001*)(memberOf=*ou=OU002*)(memberOf*ou=OU003*))"
```

The `|` denotes you're using an `OR` for your list and the `*` should act as wildcards

Also, just a suggestion when you're using tags with a ton of attributes, I've found it easier to use an `attributeCollection` to define what i'm passing into the tag. It's a personal preference for readability and has no affect on performance.

```
<cfset stldap = {}>
<cfset stldap.name = "user_info">
<cfset stldap.action = "QUERY">
<cfset stldap.server = "123.45.6.78">
<cfset stldap.attributes = "displayName, givenName, memberOf">
<cfset stldap.start = "dc=na,dc=company,dc=lan">
<cfset stldap.scope = "subtree">
<cfset stldap.filter = "(|(memberOf=*ou=OU001*)(memberOf=*ou=OU002*)(memberOf*ou=OU003*))">
<cfset stldap.username = userName>
<cfset stldap.password = passWord>

<cfldap attributeCollection="#stldap#">
```